# If-else statement tackling

Tags: c, if-statement

I am very confused about if-else statement problem.

The problem is this : using scanf function, assign total(double) and # of absences(int) to s, a, respectively.

Then, print out score based on standards below
if total is above 70, print out A+. In this condition, if absence date is more than 5 days, print out D.

if total is below 70, print out "A0" In this condition, if absence is more than 5 days, print out F.

In coding, you can use only 3 of if-else statement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double s;
    int a;
    scanf("%lf%d", &s, &a);
    if (_________________ )
         __________________
         _________________
         _________________
    else
        __________________
        __________________
        ________________
        __________________
        return 0; }
```

How I approached the problem is this. The total divides into two section, which is divided by the score 70. And then I put another nested if condition to regulate the effect of absence date
like 
    if
        if
However, the problem arises out of this. I can't do like
    if
        if
    else
        if
because if can't be included in else statement!!!. I can't use elseif statement neither!!
I want to code like

```
if total >70
    if absence > 5
if total <70
    if absence >5
```

but the thing is that I can use only if-else 3 statement... Is there any to shorten the code?

Comment: Always use braces - then you never get caught with your trousers down

Comment: and always indent properly your code (most editors do that automatically)

Comment: Here's another condition:  what happens if the score *is* 70?  You state what to do if it's greater or less, but not when it's equal.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the conditional operator (`?:`)? If you are, you can ditch the if-else statements all together.

Comment: updated my code, check if it works for you

Comment: There is no `elseif` statement - `else if` is simply the same as `else { if` with the optional `{...}` omitted, and idiomatically the `if` following `else` is not indented to simulate the `elseif` of other languages.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are doing something wrong at the level of syntax (although the logic is fine). The following snippet should work:

```
if (total > 70) {
    if (absence > 5) {
       printf("D");
    } else {
       printf("A+");
    }
} else {
    if (absence > 5) {
       printf("F");
    } else {
       printf("A0");
    }
}
```

Note that in this case, braces are not needed at all since each if statement contains just one statement. However, I have added them for clarity. I suggest you do the same until you get some practice and then you can start removing them when you see they are not needed.

Comment: From what I understand, he's only limited to using three if-else statements. This one's using 6.

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais I think you're counting wrong because the `if` and `else` get counted as a single `if-else` statement, AFAICT.  So, just count the `if` and you'll see there are only 3

Comment: @CraigEstey Ah I see. I do am counting it wrong. Sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the conditional operator (`?:`) and ditch the `if-else` statement altogether.

```
printf("%s", (total > 70) ? ((absence > 5) ? "D" : "A+") : ((absence > 5) ? "F" : "A0"));
```

Comment: @EdHeal I gotta agree. It does make the code a bit unreadable. But since he's only limited to three `if-else` statements, this can be an alternative. In any case he's not limited, I don't recommend using the conditional operator (`?:`).

Comment: I concur with your statement

Comment: Here's an [explanation](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programming/c-conditional-operators/).

Comment: I decided to jump in with an answer that uses `?:` but I combined it with an `if` to make it more readable.  To me, _nested_ `?:` statements are somewhat like too much paprika :-).  Sometimes, they're necessary in some situations (e.g. inside macros). Side note: H/W logic designers writing RTL for logic circuit design (e.g. verilog), make _heavy_ use of nested conditional operators

Comment: Oh never knew that! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use && to make something happen without multiple statements try this prototype.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int total = 71;
    int absence = 6;

    if (total > 70 && absence < 5){
        printf("A+");
        return 0;
    }
    if (total < 70 && absence < 5){
        printf("A0");
        return 0;
    }
    if (total > 70 && absence > 5   ){
        printf("D");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("F");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I should be able to print D now @Sean

Comment: Now that's better. But it would be better if you use `else if` though so that it won't have to check every single condition in every `if` statement.

Comment: but the question has "if can't be included in else statement" by @Chanyoung

Comment: Skipped that part. My bad.

Comment: also, " I can't use elseif statement neither!!"

Answer (score 0):

[just to totally confuse things :-)], here's a hybrid of paul92's and Sean's code:

```
if (total > 70)
    printf("%s",(absence > 5) ? "D" : "A+");
else
    printf("%s",(absence > 5) ? "F" : "A0");
```

Personally, I think the nested if/else is the cleanest solution, but this illustrates a [possibly] cleaner way to use the ternary `?:` operator here.

Comment: This is a cleaner one I gotta say. And it's only one `if-else` statement. But I tend to add curly braces in `if-else` statements even if it only contains one statement.

Comment: @SeanBallais Technically, we should count the `?:` as an if-else, so it's still 3 ;-).  My style is to use curly's only if needed. linux kernel source does this. To me, it's cleaner, particularly since I always have a one line comment above the if _and_ the else [for _intent_] with a blank line in between [the if-else block is wrapped in blanks]. Here, it was too trivial for that. From a study: Reading horizontally just involves eye movement. Vertical requires a slight head tilt [using neck muscles]. Try it yourself. Read a paragraph and notice the subtle head movement going line-to-line.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. But hey, we got our preferences.